# Determine a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and a basis $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

We have tha matrix \begin{equation*}A:=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 5 & 8 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 &  0 \\ 3 & 3 & 8 & 2 \\ 4 & 2 & 6 & 0 \\ 5 & 1 & 8 & 2\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{5\times 4}\end{equation*}

Determine a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and a basis $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $M_C^B(A)$ contains at the left upper corner the unit matrix and everywhere else zeroes.

Could you give me a hint for that?

So do we have to write each column of $A$ as a linear combination of $C$ and the corresponding coefficients have to satisfy the desired form that $M$ will have?

Answer (score 0):

> So do we have to write each column of $A$ as a linear combination of $C$ and the corresponding coefficients have to satisfy the desired form that $M$ will have?

If I understand you correctly, then yes. More explicitly, if $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_4\}$ and $C=\{c_1,\dots, c_5\}$ are bases of of $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^5$, respectively, and $M^B_C(A)$ looks like

$$M^B_C(A)=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1&\beta_1&\gamma_1&\delta_1\\
\alpha_2&\beta_2&\gamma_2&\delta_2\\
\alpha_3&\beta_3&\gamma_3&\delta_3\\
\alpha_4&\beta_4&\gamma_4&\delta_4\\
\alpha_5&\beta_5&\gamma_5&\delta_5\end{pmatrix},$$

then that means that $b_1$ is mapped to $\alpha_1 c_1+\dots+\alpha_5c_5$, while $b_2$ is mapped to $\beta_1c_1+\dots+\beta_5c_5$, and so on. Now you *want* it to look like

$$M_C^B(A)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

So $b_1$ should be mapped to $c_1$, $b_2$ to $c_2$, and so on. The easiest way to find such bases would be to just take the standard base as $B$. Then look at the vector to which $b_i$ is mapped and choose that as $c_i$. Then choose some additional vector as $c_5$ which completes the base.

Comment: So do we take as a basis B the set $\left \{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\right\}$ and as a basis C the set $\left \{(1,0,0,0, 0), (0,1,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0,0), (0,0,0,1,0,(0,0,0,0,1))\right\}$?

Comment: Now I am thinking about that again and I got stuck right now. We say $b_1$ is mapped to $c_1$, that doesn't mean that $b_1=c_1$, right? Because $b_1$ has $4$ components and $c_1$ has $5$ components.

Comment: $b_1$ being mapped to $c_1$ means that $Ab_1=c_1$. You have to calculate what that is (or know how to read it from the matrix directly).

Comment: By A you mean the given matrix?

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes, exactly.

Comment: That means that $c_i$ is the i-th column of the given matrix A, right?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Ok! How do we find the 5th element of the basis?

Comment: Do we maybe take the cross product of two of the existing vectors?

Comment: The cross product is only defined on $\mathbb R^3$. But you could find a system of equations using the dot product: $c_1\cdot c_5=0,\dots, c_4\cdot c_5=0$, which will determine $c_5$ up to a scaling factor.